# Setup puppet and install apache package issues

Tags: apache, ubuntu, module, puppet

For test purposes I wanted to setup puppet and deploy apache on Ubuntu 16.4 puppet master using puppet without bothering with using nodes by using the following steps:

```
$ wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet5-release-xenial.deb
```

Install the package by running:

```
$ dpkg –i puppet5-release-xenial.deb
```

Update package list

```
$ apt-get update
```

Install puppet server

```
$ sudo apt-get install puppetserver
```

On our Puppet server, install the puppetlabs-apache module:

```
$ sudo puppet module install puppetlabs-apache
```

From within the manifests directory, an init.pp class needs to be created
/etc/puppet/modules/apache/manifests/init.pp

```
class apache2 {
    package {'apache2':
          ensure => 'present',
    }
}
```

To try to install the apache package I used:

```
$ sudo puppet apply init.pp
```

I then got the following:

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for osboxes.home in environment production in 0.03 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.04 seconds
```

And when I check if apache is installed, it is not.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Apache module in the correct module path, then the problem is you don't have any code to include the module.

To keep it simple, let's forget about the file structure on the Puppet master and so forth and just create a file apache.pp (save it in /tmp or anywhere you like) and give it this content:

```
class apache2 {
    package {'apache2':
        ensure => 'present',
    }
}

include apache2
```

Now try:

```
$ sudo puppet apply apache.pp
```

You should see Puppet install the apache2 package.

However, by convention, and also for proper integration with the Puppet master, you need to now place this content in expected file locations.

The class apache (the code you already had) needs to be in a file `${modulepath}/apache2/manifests/init.pp`.

This is to satisfy Puppet's *autoloader*. You can find out more about that [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_namespaces.html#autoloader-behavior).

Meanwhile, the *modulepath* is documented [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/dirs_modulepath.html), and it can vary depending on the version of Puppet, and how you set everything up.

To find out your modulepath try:

```
$ sudo puppet config print modulepath
```

Now, if you have all the files in place, you should next be able to include that class in a different way, like this:

```
$ sudo puppet apply -e "include apache2"
```

Once you get that working, it's time to read about the [roles and profiles](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.2/r_n_p_intro.html) pattern.

Comment: An interesting side note is he installed the `puppetlabs-apache` module, presumably to utilize it, but is not actually doing so. Maybe add a quick note about that too?

Comment: Oh. That wasn't so noticeable due to the formatting and I missed it (I edited the formatting just now to fix that). Hm. Yes. That changes everything! I'll add an update.